# Creating a filter in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a db with offers:

each offer has a name, a date, a price and a supplier + for every date, there is an offer which is a "default offer".

I would like to make a filter that gives me all the offers for the date which are inferior in price to the price of the default offer for that date. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data stored in ElasticSearch, you can use the elasticsearch filter to query for the data based on that date. then you can extract what you need from the docuements. 
Something similar can be implemented if you're using SQL or whatever.

```
elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["es-server"]
            query => "date:%{[date]}"
            sort => "price:desc
            fields => { "@timestamp" => "started" }
         }
```